# Create a default signature in the mail app with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, macos-mail-app

I tried to use this code:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set newSignatureContent to "Content of the new signature"
    set newSignatureName to "NewSignature"
    
    -- Create the signature
    set newSignature to make new signature with properties {content:newSignatureContent, name:newSignatureName}
    
    -- Set the signature as default for all existing accounts
    set allAccounts to every account
    repeat with currentAccount in allAccounts
        set signatures of currentAccount to {newSignature}
        set **default signature** of currentAccount to newSignature
    end repeat
end tell
```

but I get a Syntax Error. A class name cant go after this application constant or consideration and  **default signature** is highleted, can you help me understand what is wrong here?

I tried to figure out a way to this coding the clicks on buttons but that's even more difficult and creates other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Account's **default (or selected) signature** property doesn't exist.
2. Exists Mail.app's **selected signature** property, which when setting to NAME of some signature, makes it selected (default) for IMAP accounts (such as "Gmail" account)

So, I am on Catalina. For my iCloud account following script doesn't work, but works for  my Gmail account:

```
-- script: Create new Signature & make it default signature
-- tested: on Catalina
-- written: by me, right now

set newSignatureContent to "Content of the new signature"
set newSignatureName to "NewSignature"

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    
    -- Create the signature
    make new signature with properties {content:newSignatureContent, name:newSignatureName}
    
    -- Set default signature for my Gmail accounts to the NAME of created signature
    set selected signature to "NewSignature"
    
end tell
```

NOTE: you can set selected signature to constants **randomly**, **sequentially**, or **none**, as well.